# How to implement multiple attachments to messages? in mailboxer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am using the `Mailboxer gem`.

What is the best way to set up my controller so it saves all the attachments? (loop through it?)

Would making a new model called `message_attachment` be a good idea? In that case, how do I set up the message model (which I currently don't have in my model folder) so I can include `has_many :message_attachments` please provide me a solution or a sample code
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you path.

First off, you need to fork the repository and make changes in `Mailboxer::Message` model for

1. Remove existing mounted uploader which allows to upload a single attachment
2. Define associations `has_many :attachments`
3. Allows nested attributes using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments`

Then you can add `Mailboxer::Attachment` model and associate it with `Mailboxer::Message` using `belogns_to :message`

After that modify the relevant controller to permit attachments  assuming your form is passing attributes following rails convention for nested attributes.

Comment: thanks for your reply, do i need to make new model with name "attachment"? actually i m not clear with this "Define associations has_many :attachments"

Comment: still i'm not able to save attachments

i have done followings - in message model 
  has_many :attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
and at the time of send message in controller -
 conversation = current_user.send_message(recipient, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject], true, nil, conversation_params[:attachments_attributes]).conversation